# Showing an IsBusy indicator on MainFrame when navigating between Silverlight pages

Tags: multithreading, silverlight-4.0, navigation

I am using the Silverlight 4 Navigation Framework and have pages that take some time to load (normally binding to large amounts of data).

I have put a IsBusy SL Toolkit control on the MainFrame and I want to set it to Busy when you click on the navigation to another page, and set it to NotBusy when the other page has finished loading.

To keep it simple and get it working first, I am excluding MVVM and just using code-behind calls, but my IsBusy control never appears. I assume it is a UI threading issue but I need some help please.

**EDIT**: On a simple page, the IsBusy control IS appearing, but only once the requested page is loaded (and then it is turned off, hence you never see it). I need the calling page to invoke the IsBusy control on the parent frame and display it before it tried to even load the next page...

Here is the XAML on my MainFrame page:

```
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <navigation:Frame
            x:Name="ContentFrame"... NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed">
            <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
                   ...
            </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
        </navigation:Frame>

        <telerik:RadBusyIndicator
            x:Name="busyIndicator"
            BusyContent="Please wait..." />
    </Grid>
```

and here is the code on a page which navigates to another page:

```
    private void workorderButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MainPage) App.GetApp.RootVisual).busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("WorkOrderView", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

and then on the destination page:

```
    public WorkOrderView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ((MainPage)App.GetApp.RootVisual).busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
    }
```

I've tried so many different options but the indicator never shows up. I tried wrapping it in some threading code and then it displayed but threw an invalid cross thread exception.

I tested the XAML using this code (a button on the same page) and it works fine (shows and hides):

```
    private void btnIsBusy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MainPage)App.GetApp.RootVisual).busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3 * 1000);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => ((MainPage)App.GetApp.RootVisual).busyIndicator.IsBusy = false);
        });
    }
```

I'm sure it's something to do with the UI thread... any help appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the `INavigationContentLoader` interface introduced in Silverlight 4, which gives you a great place to hook into the navigation system and do things "globally" (across all navigations) like this.

See David Poll's blog post on doing something very simliar to this, here : http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/02/01/on-demand-loading-of-assemblies-with-silverlight-navigation-revisited-for-silverlight-4-beta/

He happens to be doing something much more complex than you need (loading pages out of remote XAPs) but look at what he's doing with the BusyIndicator control, and hopefully it's fairly easy to see how to strip out and use just that piece (he provides source for all his stuff, so you can dig in as much as you like).

If that looks like more work than is necessary for your project, another way you might be able to accomplish it is to hook into `Frame.Navigated` and `Frame.Navigating` - create a Boolean property on the control hosting the Frame, set it to true in `Frame.Navigating` and back to false in `Frame.Navigated` and use data-binding to bind that Boolean property to your IsBusy control.

Comment: Thanks once again Austin, I will look at that. I really am curious as to why this is not working though - in it's simplest form. I noticed that on a simple page the IsBusy indicator IS actually showing, but only on the page that it navigates too (it does a lot of loading in it's constructor). I would like it to show on the calling page (it's actually on the frame element, it's just invoked from the calling page). It's something to do with the UI thread and I would really like to understand it...

Comment: I think you're right that the UI thread is getting locked up.  Implementing an INavigationContentLoader may give you more flexibility to control timing, but one problem is going to be that if your Page does a lot of work on the UI thread, it will lock up UI (at least on the desktop, the Windows Phone version of Silverlight is better here with a separate Render Thread, which hopefully can make it into Silverlight 5).  The best I can say is try to make the complex work (large data analysis, etc...) happen on a background thread to minimize this.

Comment: Ok, thanks - how about something silly like calling a pause on the thread after I set IsBusy to true so that it displays the box and then starts the complicated loading? Sounds terribly hacky!

Comment: Anything you do to block the thread would cause the same problem.  I'd say try out my approach above, see if you still see the problem.  If so, posting a bit more code might help - like showing how your pages are doing so much as to cause the UI thread to lock up.

Comment: The culprit code is the Effiproz isolated storage database. We retrieve around 60 megs of data from webservices and write it to our local database on a check out. The user can then work disconnected and check it back in later. As soon as it writes/reads from the local DB it blocks the thread, so now I am trying to use a BackgroundWorker for the grid loading (I use Virtualization on the Telerik grid so it's not the binding at fault here). I am under a lot of time pressure hence I need to get this working ASAP (although I do want to look at the Nav framework solution ultimately!)